# socket.readBytes not moving pointer

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets

I'm running into a strange issue trying to use ByteArrays to send an object and unsigned int over a Socket. I'm trying to handle a case where I may receive data in multiple packets.

Here is my socket data handler:

```
protected function handleSocketData(e:ProgressEvent):void{
        var s:Socket = e.target as Socket;

        trace("pre if " + len + " " + s.bytesAvailable);
        if (len == 0 && s.bytesAvailable >= 4) {
            len = s.readUnsignedInt();

        }

        trace(len + " " + s.bytesAvailable);
        if (len > 0 && s.bytesAvailable >= len){
            var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            //s.readBytes(ba, 0, len);
            s.readBytes(ba, 0, s.bytesAvailable); //should be len

            //trace("handle socket before inflate " + ba.length);
            ba.inflate();
            //trace("handle socket after inflate " + ba.length);
            var o:Object = ba.readObject();
            Overlord.updatePlayers(o);
            trace(o.player);
            len = 0;


        }
}
```

The problem lies with `s.readBytes(ba, 0, len);`

I'm using len (defined at the class scope) to handle a case where I may get multiple packets. Now this seems to work the **first** time I get data over the socket.

```
pre if 0 44 - trace I'm getting before the first if statement
38 40 - trace I'm getting after
frank - Everything comes in fine, working!
```

Now if I send data over the socket again:

```
**first send:**
pre if 0 44
38 40
frank - working, yay!
**things start to fail every send after:**
pre if 0 46
218759168 42
pre if 218759168 84
218759168 84
pre if 218759168 127
218759168 127
```

Now it seems like readBytes is leaving data in the buffer.

The strange part is when I swap `s.readBytes(ba, 0, len);` for `s.readBytes(ba, 0, s.bytesAvailable);` everything seems to work:

**With s.readBytes(ba, 0, s.bytesAvailable);**

```
**first send**
pre if 0 44
38 40
frank
**everything seems to work after, no old data in the buffer?**
pre if 0 44
38 40
frank
pre if 0 43
37 39
frank
```

The issue with using `bytesAvailable` is that now I can't handle multiple packets.

```
pre if 2214 2218
2214 2218
RangeError: Error #2006: The supplied index is out of bounds.
at flash.utils::ByteArray/readObject()
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm missing here, it seems like the buffer is only getting cleared when I use socket.bytesAvailable. Anyone have any input?

**edit**

I'm using this method for sending data over the socket. By writing the length of the ByteArray and reading it back in the data handler I'm trying to handle getting the data object across multiple packets.

```
        public function sendData(socketData:*):void{
        if(_connected){
            //trace("sending");
            var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            ba.writeObject(socketData);
            ba.position = 0;
            //trace("byteArray len before send and defalte: " + ba.length)
            ba.deflate();
            //trace("byteArray len before send and after defalte: " + ba.length)
            socket.writeUnsignedInt(ba.length);
            socket.writeBytes(ba, 0, ba.length);
            socket.flush();
        } else {
            throw new Error("Socket not open");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify the purpose of setting the byte array length as len = s.readUnsignedInt()?

Comment: @AscensionSystems I'm attaching the length of the ByteAArray to the packet in an attempt to handle the possibility of getting the object back over multiple packets

Comment: Ok I'll have to check out your updated answer later on, I'm been up all night working on my own projects so it's time for bed. lol Sorry

Comment: Did you check raw content of what you are getting on the client side? Try reading all the stuff you get up to socket.bytesAvailable, and printing it in hex form to see all the bytes you've got. Use `readUnsignedByte()`, `toString(16)` and add leading zero for numbers lesser than 16. If you see, that the bytes you are getting are exactly what were expected, then it will strongly point out that the client side implementation is wrong.

Comment: @NoxNoctis thanks for that comment. I will give this a try tonight and post my results.

Comment: In my current project I handle binary input from a socket with a class, that acts as a cellular automaton. It has 3 states:

 1. waiting for command id
 2. waiting for command length
 3. waiting for command body

Upon receiving ProgressEvent my class executes a routine according to current state.

In each state I wait for `socket.bytesAvailable` to become `>=` the expected length, then I read that exactly amount of data and switch to the next state. So,I read data only when sufficient bytes are available at the socket, just like you do.

This works perfectly robust, never had any issues there.

Comment: @NoxNoctis interesting approach. My goal here is eventually to have something that robust. I'm really quite lost as to why this is not handling on object across multiple packets.

Comment: Hey, any progress there?

Comment: @NoxNoctis still an open question but I've been able to move past this issue in my current project. I was able to switch over to zmq and use it's as3 wrapper class. http://www.zeromq.org/deleted:bindings:actionscript-zmqsocket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really pull the data out of the socket into a byte array and then do your manipulations on the bytearray and not the socket. When you call any of the read***() methods on the socket or a bytearray, you move the .position property by the value of your read method. This is also the reason why you're getting the supplied index error on readObject. Before calling readObject, set the .position property of BA to 0 first.

```
 ba.position = 0;
 var o:Object = ba.readObject();
```

My comment on your question and the details in this answer I believe are at the very least a fundamental issue with your code. You should also post the code of the sending socket so that we can figure this out easier.

Comment: Understood. But it looks like the issue I'm having only comes into play when I get the object back across multiple packets. The code seems to work for a single packet. I've updated my question with the code for sending the data over the socket

Comment: Not setting `position` in ba is not really an issue *here*. [After the call to inflate ... The position property is set to 0.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#inflate%28%29) But in general, I agree, it's safer to explicitly set position.